# Creating newsletter in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, email, newsletter

For my silverlight project I'm creating a newsletter which can be send through a certain page.

For this I have a newsletter service which can be seen here:

```
       public bool SendMail(string emailTo, string emailFrom, string msgSubject, string msgBody)
    {
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailTo));
            msg.Subject = msgSubject;
            msg.Body = msgBody;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Replace with your servers IP address
            smtp.Port = 465;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Send(msg);
            success = true;
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            success = false;
        }

        return success;

    }
```

And I ask the service to send the mail with the following code:

```
   public partial class Nieuwsbrief : UserControl
{
    IEnumerable<Inschrijvingen> ingeschrevenen = null;

    public Nieuwsbrief()
    {
        InschrijvingenServiceClient personclient = new InschrijvingenServiceClient();

        personclient.getInschrijvingenCompleted += new EventHandler<getInschrijvingenCompletedEventArgs>(personclient_getInschrijvingenCompleted);
        personclient.getInschrijvingenAsync();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NieuwsbriefServiceClient client = new NieuwsbriefServiceClient();

        //foreach (Inschrijvingen person in ingeschrevenen)
        //{
            client.SendMailAsync("test@gmail.com", "nieuwsbrief@ondernemersaward.be", txtSubject.Text, txtContent.Text);
        //}

        client.SendMailCompleted += new EventHandler<SendMailCompletedEventArgs>(client_SendMailCompleted);
    }

    void personclient_getInschrijvingenCompleted(object sender, getInschrijvingenCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ingeschrevenen = e.Result;
    }

    void client_SendMailCompleted(object sender, SendMailCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            txtContent.Text = "Mail has NOT send!" + e.Error.ToString();
        else
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
    }
}
```

However when I press `btnSubmit` nothing happens, untill I shut down the server and then I get the following error:

```
Mail has NOT send!System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at OndernemersAward.NieuwsbriefServiceReference.NieuwsbriefServiceClient.NieuwsbriefServiceClientChannel.EndSendMail(IAsyncResult result)
   at OndernemersAward.NieuwsbriefServiceReference.NieuwsbriefServiceClient.OndernemersAward.NieuwsbriefServiceReference.NieuwsbriefService.EndSendMail(IAsyncResult result)
   at OndernemersAward.NieuwsbriefServiceReference.NieuwsbriefServiceClient.OnEndSendMail(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

I hope somebody can help me,
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your catch statement do this:

```
catch (Exception e)
{   //<---- Put the break point here.

}
```

You can then see 'e' and see why this is failing.

My guess is that it's `smtp.Send` that's failing, and it can throw [a lot of exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx), so I won't venture to guess which one!

EDIT: Also, where it says "// Replace with your servers IP address", did you replace it with your server's IP address?  I first assumed you posted demo code, but I want to be sure.

Well, this is your problem!  Gmail lets you use them as an smtp server.  Use them: http://www.geekzone.co.nz/tonyhughes/599.  You have to change your smtp.Port to 465 and the smtp.Host to smtp.gmail.com.  This requires authentication, so go create a gmail account.

Comment: I don't have a server, so I'm just trying to run it from localhost, I hope that isn't a problem?

Comment: Yes.  That's your problem.  It's going to throw an exception saying there is no SMTP server there.  See my edit.

Comment: Ah thanks, is there any way I can make it work on localhost? With like gmail's smtp server?

Comment: Humpf, I'm getting a different error now. :( 
I editted my first post.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail